# Class not found error after publishing website

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have created a web application with 3 layers and trying to publish in my localhost. But I am getting an error saying that a class is not found - which is actually in my businesslayer assembly.

Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Employee' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 ***Employee objEmployee = new Employee();***

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }
}
```

Comment: And you're sure you have references from all dlls to the main www (or whatever the main web project is called) assembly?

Comment: yes, same is working fine when running from visualstudio

Comment: Does your site folder has enough permission? could you share which permission you assigned to the folder? and what is your site folder path? You could also refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246) for detail.